# How can my wife have her cake if I won't eat it too?

Tags: politeness, marriage

My wife's birthday is coming up next week, and I'm looking to get her a cake - she rarely ever has gotten her very own birthday cake, and I want to get her something she will really appreciate.

She has told me that her preference is for a cheesecake with cherry topping.

This presents a problem though - I do not like cheesecake at all.  As I am the only one who will be there with her (We prefer private birthdays), I feel like it would be awkward for her to have a whole cheesecake and see me not having anything.

She did mention that she would also like yellow cake with chocolate frosting, but I feel like this would be a substitute to what she's really asking for - and I feel like if I got just one slice of cake for me and a whole cheesecake for her, she would still feel awkward (and that getting one slice of cheesecake for her and a whole yellow cake would be equally awkward).

I do not want to just get two slices of different cake either - as the real draw of this is for her to have an entire cake made for her birthday.

What can I do so that my wife won't feel awkward about getting so much cheesecake?

Comment: "What should I do" questions are off topic, please edit to make it a specific interpersonal goal you want to achieve. Asking your wife her preferences? Communicating to each other your wants?

Comment: @ElizB Ah, I admit I didn't know that was off-topic...so I think I'll just have to leave this closed.

Comment: If you are still looking for answers, edit the question to be about interpersonal goal you want to achieve, then we can help you.

Answer (score 8):

Get...both?

My local grocery store sells whole cheesecakes, single slices of cheesecake, and variety packs of cheesecake slices.

Buy as much cheesecake as you think she'll eat, then make a small cake that can be for both of you. That way she has something home-made **AND** what you know she actually wants.

Comment: So...buy a cheesecake and a yellow cake?  Won't that leave a lot of leftover cake?

Comment: A lot of times shops sell small cakes or a variety of sizes.  So you might be able to get a small cheesecake AND a small cake with chocolate frosting.

Comment: Cake keeps for quite a long time, and you can freeze it. I don't see how having a lot of leftover cake is a problem :]

Comment: @Zibbobz not the worst problem to have :)